# can frontend-maven-plugin use node, npm already installed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, maven, npm, gruntjs

I am new using maven and frontend-maven-plugin. I understand that we can add this code to pom.xml to run grunt for example:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- NB! Set <version> to the latest released version of    frontend-maven-plugin, like in README.md -->
            <version>@project.version@</version>

            <executions>

                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v5.3.0</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>3.3.12</npmVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <!-- Optional configuration which provides for running any npm command -->
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>npm run build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run build</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>grunt build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>grunt</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>--no-color</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I actually installed  node and npm on my server 
for example: node is installed under /opt/app/trss/nodejs, npm under /opt/app/trss/nodejs/npm  how can this pom.xml use the node,npm installed on my server? Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The plugin has been designed to use a local installation of node. Using a globally installed version has been [requested before](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/issues/277) but the developer's position is that node does not take up much space and will only download if missing.

Installing node locally allows developers that have not installed node globally or are using different versions to build the project without having to do anything more complicated than `mvn clean install`.

You can use the [exec plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) run your globally installed version of npm and then grunt. Something like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
    <executions>
       <execution>
          <id>run-npm-install</id>
          <phase>compile</phase>
          <goals>
             <goal>exec</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
             <executable>npm</executable>
             <arguments>
                <argument>install</argument>
             </arguments>
           </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>run-grunt</id>
          <phase>compile</phase>
          <goals>
             <goal>exec</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
             <executable>grunt</executable>
             <arguments>
                <argument>--no-color</argument>
             </arguments>
           </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Any idea, How do I specify source and target folder in this plugin. ?

Answer (score 8):

Finally, it is now possible to skip node and npm installation as detailed below:

https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/issues/768

```xml
<execution>
    <id>install node and npm</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
    </goals>
    <phase>...</phase>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
        <nodeVersion>...</nodeVersion>
        <npmVersion>...</npmVersion>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Comment: this is missing a specification of the paths.   just adding skip tries to use the local installation which is missing

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, but it is also relevant that doing this rather than using the maven-frontend-plugin can lead to Eclipse doing the wrong thing:

```xml
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                     <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                       <pluginExecutions>
                         <pluginExecution>
                           <pluginExecutionFilter>
                             <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                             <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                             <versionRange>[1.6.0,)</versionRange>
                             <goals>
                               <goal>exec</goal>
                             </goals>
                           </pluginExecutionFilter>
                           <action>
                             <execute>
                                <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
                             </execute>
                           </action>
                         </pluginExecution>
                       </pluginExecutions>
                     </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
```