# Extra directory layer added to path with Maven compile

Tags: maven, jhipster, frontend-maven-plugin

I am trying to use maven to compile my first JHipster basic app. I have `node` as an exe & `npm` as a symbolic link locally at the path `/home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.0/bin` (see `ll` below), and *I want to use my local node & npm*, not have maven install them both. The problem is that when I run `mvn clean compile`, I get the error at bottom.

To me, the error shows that somewhere in the pom `/node/node` is being appended to the path, when I only (I think) need `/node` appended.

Where am I getting the extra `/node` from?

The pom is large, but here is my `frontend-maven-plugin` ([this](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/blob/master/README.md#installation-directory) is source for adding `<installDirectory>`):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>webapp build dev</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>run webapp:build</arguments>
                <environmentVariables>
                    <APP_VERSION>${project.version}</APP_VERSION>
                </environmentVariables>
                <npmInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>false</npmInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>
                <installDirectory>/home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.0/bin</installDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I commented out these executions due to having node/npm locally installed (listed here in brief):

```
        <id>install-node-and-npm</id>
        <goals><goal>install-node-and-npm</goal></goals>

        <id>npm install</id>
        <goals><goal>npm</goal></goals>
```

Node location

```
> ll /home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.0/bin
...
drwxr-xr-x. 2 myuser mygroup     4096 Aug 16 02:36 .
drwxr-xr-x. 6 myuser mygroup     4096 Sep 12 17:39 ..
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 myuser mygroup 82214176 Aug 16 02:36 node
...
```

Error

```
Cannot run program "/home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.0/bin/node/node" (in directory "/home/myuser/Documents/projects/jhipster/firstApp"): error=20, Not a directory
```

I can paste the 1300 line pom.xml if needed.

I tried adding the exec-maven-plugin based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37329708/can-frontend-maven-plugin-use-node-npm-already-installed), but the error persisted.

**UPDATE**
For reasons beyond this scope, using node/npm locally is currently my only option, so I do not need maven to install them.

Comment: The frontend-maven-plugin installs its own version of Node. You do not need to configure it to use yours. If you use an unmodified version of `pom.xml`, everything should work out-of-the-box.

Comment: Please see UPDATE above.

Comment: OK. I'm not sure how to change JHipster to make this work.

Comment: No worries and thanks. For now, I am assuming that somewhere in the pom is the solution.